# How or what the word "but" mean there?

Tags: prepositions

> I couldn't think a thing **but that he would be** coming to get his water again.

<sub>(excerpted from the collection of Alice Munro, the part "How I met my husband")</sub>

Have I correctly rephrased the bold part?

> […]but(for) I could think that he would be coming[…]

Comment: You need to use the dictionary and define "but that". It's a set phrase.

Comment: The sentence sounds OK, with but that meaning except that.  However, but for that means "except for/with the exception of " doesn't fit in the sentence.

Comment: What is the difference between "except for/with" and" execpt that"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Sentence**

> I couldn't think a thing but that he would be coming to get his water again.

**Your Rephrasing**

> I couldn't think a thing, but I could think that he would be coming to get his water again.

This is pretty close, but not quite right. It's essentially saying that the only thing the person can think is this one thought. However, it starts with a contradictory statement, saying that they can't think anything at all.

**"But That"**

As used in the original sentence, ["but that"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/but-that) means "except that" or "other than that".

**My Rephrasing**

Here's a minimal rephrasing:

> I couldn't think a thing except that he would be coming to get his water again.

And a more radical one:

> The only thing I could think was that he would be coming to get his water again.